# WCF REST service: how to pass the exact request of the client from one service to another?

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

I have two WCF REST services, `serviceA` and `ServiceB`.

`ServiceA` acts as just mediator between the client and `ServiceB`. I am using windows authentication in both `ServiceA` and `ServiceB` to form the windows identity of client at service side.

I have a client where I want to create windows identity at `serviceB`, but the request first goes to `ServiceA` (mediator), and `ServiceA` will pass the request on to `ServiceB`. Because of this I am not getting the windows identity of the client at `ServiceB`.

Is there any way that I can pass the request of the client as it is from `ServiceA` to `ServiceB`, so that I can use the windows identity of the client? Or is there any other way to pass the windows identity in WCF rest?

Comment: Will client and computers hosting `ServiceA` and `ServiceB` be on the same Windows domain/workgroup?

Comment: thanks for the reply Micky,  ALL three of them are in same domain

Comment: Is this an IIS-hosted WCF service utilising Integrated Windows Authentication? I don't think passing the exact [HTTP] request will help you because Windows Authentication is done prior to the request...you probably need to use Impersonation so the request from ServiceA to ServiceB appears as the same client.

Comment: Thanks for the reply scheinder, i have tried that impersonation as well in the service A, but still somehow the serviceA is not able to authenticate against the serviceB, .e it is throwing the unAuthorized exception